# DateDiff returns negative value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing some calculation in SQL Query using `DateDiff` function. My Calculation went wrong if `DateDiff` Value came in negative

```
Declare @ActualTime Numeric(10,2)=677.00

Select Convert(Numeric(10,2),(100*((@ActualTime-(Convert(Numeric(10,2),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute,VendorTicketRaisedOn ,ClosedOn)) / 60)+'.'+
      Right('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, VendorTicketRaisedOn , ClosedOn)) % 60),2))))/@ActualTime*1)))[AGS Uptime %]
      From Ticket
```

Two Columns `VendorTicketRaisedOn` & `ClosedOn` are of type `DateTime`. If `ClosedOn` > `VendorTicketRaisedOn` Then Value Came in negetive.

**How to treat this case to produce result as 0 ?**

**If Value is in negative then DateDiff should give output as 0 instead of -value**

DB : SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Could you explain your compution a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
Declare @ActualTime Numeric(10,2)=677.00

SELECT CASE WHEN ClosedOn > VendorTicketRaisedOn 
            THEN 0
       ELSE Convert(Numeric(10,2),(100*((@ActualTime-(Convert(Numeric(10,2),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,VendorTicketRaisedOn ,ClosedOn)) / 60)+'.'+ Right('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, VendorTicketRaisedOn , ClosedOn)) % 60),2))))/@ActualTime*1)))
      END AS [AGS Uptime %]
FROM Ticket
```